# Synonymize 'osx' and 'mac-os-x' (and possibly 'mac'?)

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Can we synonymize [osx](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) to point to [mac-os-x](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-x)? It doesn't make sense to have both, and the latter seems to fit our scheme best.

Also, can we do something with [mac](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) while we're at it? We have [mac-address](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-address) already, so it's also redundant (and confusing) and is also being used in almost every case to refer to the OS rather than a MAC address. I don't know if it should be synonymized or stay around to maybe refer to generic Mac (as in Apple) hardware, but currently it seems confusing. Maybe [macintosh](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macintosh) makes more sense? I'm not entirely privy to the naming conventions of Apple's hardware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made [mac-os-x](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-x) the parent of both [osx](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) and [mac](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac).  The latter only had one about MAC addresses (which I retagged) and I don't think we had any questions about pre-OSX Macs.